# Why won't my iFrame widen like I need it to?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a scroll bar on my page and I've linked youtube and vimeo videos into it.  The videos are showing and playing fine, but the dimensions of the iFrame are off and I don't know why its happening.

HTML:

```
<!-- section that contains all pics -->
<section id="wrapper" class="wrapper">

    <article class="post">
    <p><iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/0a9meMkn4Go" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
    </article>

    <article class="post">
    <p><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/76815334?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="853" height="480" frameborder="0" 

webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe> <p><a     href="http://vimeo.com/76815334">Beautiful Filth Bears Strange Fruit</a> from <a 

href="http://vimeo.com/kahlone">Kahleem Poole-Tejada (KahL-One)</a> on <a     href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p></p>
    </article>

    <article class="post">
    <p><iframe width="853" height="480"     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YEiK6ymugrw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
    </article>

    <article class="post">
    <p><iframe width="853" height="480" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rx6k65W5ScE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
    </article>

</section>
<!-- close section -->
```

The Corresponding CSS:

```
/* main content - scroller
------------------------------------------------------------------- */  

#wrapper {
   float:left;
   margin:110px 0 0 0;
   padding:0 0 0 250px;
   background:#fff;
   position:relative;
   z-index:2;
   border-bottom:solid 20px #fff;
}

#wrapper img {
   color:#fff;
   width:auto;
}

#wrapper iframe {
   color:#fff;
   width:auto;
}

.post {
   padding:0 10px 0 0;
   background:#fff;
   height:100%;
}
```

I am not sure why I am missing.  When I use images in this same configuration they are perfectly sized as needed.   Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `width` attribute from the iframe? Probably because of this attribute, the css rule for `width:auto;` is overridden.

Comment: try remove `width:auto` in CSS, it overridden your iframe manually width setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#wrapper iframe {
   color:#fff;
}
```

Your `width:auto` is breaking. Try viewing here:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/Mbz9z/1/

Comment: I assume this renders as you expect it to?

Comment: Huzzah!  You're a superhero!   Thank you!